# how to write a script to generate a bill summary if user entered product id and quantity in tcl?

Tags: tcl

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set fp [open "tcldata.txt" a+]
set file_data [read $fp]
close $fp
puts "enter product id: \n";
#gets user id given by user.
gets STDIN a
puts "enter quantity: \n";
#gets quantity given by user.
gets STDIN b
set id_row ()
grep read product_id [$file_data]
set product_array = split ('',$id_row);
puts "----------"
puts [llength $fp]
puts "----------"
```

Comment: This feels like you're asking someone to do your class homework assignment for you.

Answer (score 1):

First, documentation for Tcl commands is at http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm

- opening a file `a+` starts reading at the bottom of the file, so the `file_data` variable will be empty. To read from a file use access `r`. See the [`open` command](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/open.htm)
- standard input is the lowercase `stdin` -> `gets stdin productId`
- `set id_row ()` -- parentheses have no special meaning in Tcl. This commands stores a 2-character string into the `id_row` variable.
- `grep read product_id [$file_data]` -- what are you trying to do here? It would help if you put some sample data into your question
- `set product_array = split ('',$id_row);`

  - don't use `=`, the [`set` command](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/set.htm) takes at most 2 arguments
  - Tcl commands don't use parentheses around their arguments, nor commas to separate arguments, just whitespace. See the [Tcl syntax rules](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm), particularly the first 3.
- `llength $fp` -- the `fp` variable is a (closed) file descriptor. What are you trying to do here?